# UNION - MySQL vs SQLight

Tags: mysql, union

I have the following SQL-Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT sku,
               price
        FROM   pricelist_98
        UNION
        SELECT sku,
               price
        FROM   pricelist_10) AS result
WHERE  sku = '5101863'
GROUP  BY sku
```

I want to get the price from pricelist_98 when the specified products exists in there, otherwise the price from pricelist_10. This should be dynamically expandable with more and different pricelist tables. The first pricelist containing the product should be displayed.

When I query my MySQL Server I get the volitional result. I also have an iPad app with the same database structure in an SQLight database. Here I get the row from pricelist_10 as a result though the product exists in pricelist_98.

I am curious about the technical background why the query is handled differently. Also I am looking for a one-single-query-solution that works too in my SQLight database.

**EDIT** Also note that the WHERE is optional. I need the SELECT to return every product in at least one pricelist table I query.

Comment: Who created different price list tables? Have you tried SQLDark?

Comment: The reason this was done was because different customers get assigned to different pricelists and some pricelists have a base pricelist for products which have no special price for this customer. In this example pricelist_98 only contains about 10 products and has pricelist_10 as a base pricelist.
This structure is preset and I can't change anything about it.

And no, I haven't tried SQLDark. I am stuck with SQLight.

Comment: 1. Is SKU unique within a single table? 2. Why do you use GROUP BY?

Comment: SKU is unique for a product but the product can be in pricelist_98 and in pricelist_10. I need the price which is in the first pricelist I SELECT. And because I then get more than one result I use GROUP BY to get only one. MySQL gives me the price from pricelist_98 whilst SQLIght gives me the price from pricelist_10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY`, the choice of which row to return is arbitrary -- SQL doesn't impose any ordering unless you use `ORDER BY`. Here's how to specify preference explicitly:

```
SELECT main.sku, main.price
FROM   (SELECT sku,
               price,
               1 preference
        FROM   pricelist_98
        WHERE  <whatever>
        UNION
        SELECT sku,
               price,
               2 preference
        FROM   pricelist_10
        WHERE  <whatever>) AS temp1) AS main
JOIN (SELECT sku, min(preference) preference
      FROM   (SELECT sku,
                     1 preference
              FROM   pricelist_98
              WHERE  <whatever>
              UNION
              SELECT sku,
                     2 preference
              FROM   pricelist_10
              WHERE  <whatever>) AS temp2
      GROUP BY sku) AS temp3
ON main.sku = temp3.sku AND main.preference = temp3.preference
```

It's also better to put the `WHERE` clause in the subqueries. Otherwise, the database has to merge the entire tables before doing the search, instead of just merging two rows (theoretically the query optimizer could do this transformation itself, but I'd be very surprised if MySQL or SQLite did this).

There might be an efficiency gain if you create a view that implements the union with preference parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the where clause.
But unfortunatly I can't use your solution because the WHERE is optional. I need every product in the pricelist tables, so I can't use LIMIT 1.

Comment: Take the where out or move it outside then. Should get what you want, it will just be a tad inefficient

Comment: Revised the query to work for a `WHERE` clause that can match multiple SKUs. Or you can leave it out entirely, and get the entire price list.